# Couldn't install local gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install a gem that i'm developing from local.

```
gem install mygem.gemspec
```

It produces an error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mygem.gemspec' (>= 0) in any repository
```

I can't find any error why it doesn't work, what might be a problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t install the `.gemspec` file, you use that to build the gem, and then install the resulting gem.

Something like:

```
$ gem build mygem.gemspec
Successfully built RubyGem
Name: mygem
Version: 1.0.0
File: mygem-1.0.0.gem
```

and then:

```
$ gem install mygem-1.0.0.gem
Successfully installed mygem-1.0.0
1 gem installed
```

Comment: how do you use this gem in a .rb file if you also have a gemfile?